# How do I concatenate a dot to a string?

Tags: string, c++-cli, string-concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate a dot ( "." ) in a Visual C++ Windows Form Application. My code is:

```
String ^a;      
a=String::Concat(values->Text,".");

valores->Text= a;
```

But if the text already has `3`, it changes to `.3` instead of `3.`.

Changing it to:

```
a=String::Concat(".", values-> Text)
```

doesn't fix it.

Comment: We can't see the context of this code.  My crystal ball says that it appears in an event handler for a TextBox control.  Your Text property assignment sets the SelectionStart property value back to 0.  So text entered by the user is inserted at the beginning.  Randomly, valores->SelectionStart = valores->Text->Length changes that outcome.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is a RichTextBox... I'm doing a Scientific Calculator, and when I press the dut button I have this problem...

Comment: Just a question, Where do I have to put that code in the program? Sorry but I'm new in this language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a += ".";
```

( That's all there is to it! )